# Apache Tomcat not starting on Linux Server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, bash, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I am attempting to get Apache Tomcat 5 started for a customer.  (Yes, I know there are newer versions, but bear with me)  Tomcat has previously run properly on this machine, but it is older and has not been used in awhile.  It is a Linux server with a Bash shell.

Tomcat appears to be installed properly, however, when I try to start Tomcat, it says:

Starting Tomcat: Using CATALINA_BASE: /opt/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9/bin
Using CATALINA_HOME: /opt/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9/bin
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9/bin/temp
Using JRE_HOME: /usr/java/jre1.5.0_11

When I check the status, it says it is stopped.  In catalina.out, it says:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap

However, Bootstrap.jar exists in /opt/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9/bin!

I have done a lot of Googling, but no luck.  Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Your linux distribution is not a secret, is it? 'With a bash shell' doesn't really identify it uniquely, you know :)

Answer (score 2):

CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_HOME should point to:

```
/opt/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9/
```

and not to:

```
/opt/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9/bin
```